# Prevent NLog from rendering inner text when layout render output is empty

Tags: nlog

I put the contents of my NLog error email text into a file and render it using a a FileContents renderer.  What I'd like to do is hide certain parts of html output if a layout renderer produces an empty string

```
<div>Request ticket: ${httpContextItems:key=RequestTicket}</div>
```

I am not sure of the syntax of the [when condition/property](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/When-Layout-Renderer).  Here are some attempts:

```
${httpContextItems:key=RequestTicket:when:length>0}
   <div>Request ticket: ${httpContextItems:key=RequestTicket}</div>
${??? How to enclose? }
```

And NLog doesn't like this nested stuff:

```
${when:when=length(${httpContextItems:key=RequestTicket})=0:inner=<div>Request ticket: ${httpContextItems:key=RequestTicket}</div>}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem and got things to work like this:

```
${when:when=length('${httpContextItems:key=RequestTicket}') > 0:inner=&lt;div&gt;Request ticket ${httpContextItems:key=RequestTicket}&lt;/div&gt;}
```

Note that I had to drop the colon after *Request ticket*. NLog kept on cutting text before or after the colon, no matter what I tried (escaping with \, used ${literal}, replaced colon with its ASCII code, put the colon in a separate variable...).

Answer (score 1):

> And NLog doesn't like this nested stuff:
>
> ```
> ${when:when=length(${httpContextItems:key=RequestTicket})=0:inner=<div>Request    ticket: ${httpContextItems:key=RequestTicket}</div>}
> ```

This was a bug in NLog due to the colon. This should work now since NLog 4.2, so the solution is, upgrade NLog. See [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/444)