# How do i manipulate the stack level of NLog?

Tags: c#, nlog

I've got an extension method to support additional log levels like this:

```
    public static void Duration(this ILogger source, string message)
    {
        var logEventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Warn, source.Name, message);
        logEventInfo.Properties.Add("specialLevel", "Duration");
        source.Log(logEventInfo);
    }
```

There is one problem with this.

My ${callsite} now always reports Duration. Is there any way to increase the call stack level by one, to get the method which calls Duration, or do i need a custom renderer for this?

## What i tried so far:

```
logEventInfo.Properties.Add("skipFrames", 1);
```

and

```
layout="${formattedDate} ${callsite:skipFrames=${event-properties:item=skipFrames}} ${message}"
```

## Ugly workaround:

```
[LayoutRenderer("customCallSite")]
public class CustomCallSiteLayoutRenderer : CallSiteLayoutRenderer
{
    private readonly CallSiteLayoutRenderer DefaultRenderer = new CallSiteLayoutRenderer();

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        if (!logEvent.HasProperties)
        {
            builder.Append(DefaultRenderer.Render(logEvent));
            return;
        }

        if (logEvent.Properties["skipFrames"] is int skipFrames)
        {
            builder.Append(GetRenderer(skipFrames).Render(logEvent));
        }
        else
        {
            builder.Append(logEvent.Level);
        }
    }

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, CallSiteLayoutRenderer> Renderers = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, CallSiteLayoutRenderer>();

    private CallSiteLayoutRenderer GetRenderer(int skipFrames)
    {
        return Renderers.GetOrAdd(skipFrames, f => new CallSiteLayoutRenderer() {SkipFrames = skipFrames});
    }
}
```

Comment: [The `callSite` renderer has a property `skipFrames`](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Callsite-Layout-Renderer), but I'm not sure how you would implement it just for this method.

Comment: @stuartd Yup. Seen that one. It appears the issue is delegating the information accordingly.

Comment: @Julian Do you reckon this could have been done in a way which does not involve a custom renderer? given that it works - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389554/prevent-nlog-from-rendering-inner-text-when-layout-render-output-is-empty did not work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another approach you can follow

1. Move the "Duration" method to a new assembly
2. Hide that assembly in the stacktraces, by calling [AddHiddenAssembly](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.5.0/html/M_NLog_LogManager_AddHiddenAssembly.htm)

   ```cs
   LogManager.AddHiddenAssembly(yourAssemblyWithDurationMethod)
   ```

No need for custom layout renderers then :)

PS: Your "Duration" method should be named "LogDuration". ;)  From an API-viewpoint it's a bit odd method in my opinion.

Comment: That solution seems very nice too! And yes - the customer wants it for his project. Personally i think ordinary log levels work just fine and the custom log levels are nonsense, since they are outside of the scope of log level ordinals...